# Checkpoints in Pentaho Spoon

Tags: pentaho

The pentaho documentation (http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Job+checkpoints+and+restartability) specifies that, as of version 5.0, you can define "checkpoints" and "checkpoint logs" to let you restart ETL jobs from the most recently failed point so you don't have to go back and re-run a bunch of steps that already completed successfully.

I'm running Pentaho Data Integration 5.0.1 and I don't see any of these features in Spoon. Any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using pdi-ce-5.0 community edition. These feature are available in Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 1):

Check pointing is an enterprise edition feature in 5.0. If you are a paid customer, contact support for help in debugging the issue. You may be using the wrong product. If you are a community edition user, you will have to build check points into your ETL manually. This can a good reason to purchase the enterprise edition. If restatability is important to your company, writing it by hand requires extra coding and cause defects.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing that with the community version is as follows, with the kettle you do an output to a file in which you save the state where he stayed before failing, for example:
[last run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZJaH.png)

in this file you will have the last value you choose to be your chekpoint, and if it fails, you know where he stayed before giving error can then use the value you have in this file as a parameter of your transformation or job, and specify that Begin from that value, or you can do it manually, excuse my English, this rusty