# Connection between pentaho and mysql is reset

Tags: mysql, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

Whenever I'm in the middle of a "big" transformation, at some (random) moment the connection between Pentaho and MySQL is reset and I need to start all over again.

Is there any way to prevent this error or at least continue the transformation where it left off?

I tried running the transformation again trying to get it to the end.

Comment: Transactional databases tend to roll back once the connection is aborted. I cannot tell the nature of the Pentaho transform however I suspect there is no easy repeat. Do the server logs show why the connection was aborted? Include these in the question, Which MySQL version? What is the Pentaho transform?

Answer (score 0):

The answer for the Pentaho Community Edition is No. However, for the Pentaho Enterprise edition, you have the ability to restart the job where it was last run using `Checkpoints`. The details of which are available in the below links:

1. [Use checkpoints to restart jobs](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/9.0/Products/Use_checkpoints_to_restart_jobs)
2. [Checkpoints in Pentaho Spoon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190843/checkpoints-in-pentaho-spoon) for the alternative CE edition answer.